# How to add data availability statement in Physical Review Letters?

Tags: publications, journals, data, open-access, open-science

We have submitted our recent findings to PRL. As the second round of revision came through, we are almost confident that we will get published in PRL.

Now we wanted to provide our algorithm as a matlab GUI so that the readers can reproduce our results in a single click. The idea is to motivate readers from other fields to have a quick feel of what we do.

Most journals like nature have a Data availability where they allow to provide links to available data. Is there a way in PRL to do such thing. We would like to add a link to our webpage which has the software created by us.

For example,

> Data availability: Interested readers can reproduce our results by using our algorithm. The software can be found at [URL].

Is such a statement allowed in PRL? If so where does it go, before acknowledgments or after that or in the supplemental?

Comment: *Is such a statement allowed in PRL?* At a guess: probably. Read the guidelines of PRL to confirm. *If so where does it go, before acknowledgments or after that or in the supplemental?* The statement is crucial for anyone that wants to re-run your algorithm, so I think it belongs in the main body of the paper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have experience with PRL, only with an APS journal(Physical Review x, where x=A-E[not all of them, only an undisclosed letter]). First of all, I would like to congratulate you, having a paper in PRL it is really something to be appreciated. For PRL, you can add supplemental material to the paper, which can be downloaded when the user downloads the original paper attached to it. As for the program which is based on a Matlab GUI, you can add a link in the body of the paper. I have seen that some authors also add links in the Acknowledgements section of the paper, where they also state that any data is available on e-mail also upon request. Also, if you used Matlab, please provide all the necessary files and the Matlab version to be used. Please use a public open access repository which will not change it's DNS in time. Moreover, don't forget that you might need to cite also Matlab as a bibtex, it might be a necessity when using this software product (see the copyright files when you installed this software on your computer).

Comment: I've found PRL often puts links to data archives in a small paragraph just before the acknowledgments.